# ado command object syntax error

Tags: asp-classic, parameters, command, adodb

I am trying to change some existing code from constructed sql string to stored procedure. here is the error.

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro error '80040e14'

Syntax error.

I have checked connection details, they are fine, I have checked values of parameters and they are fine.

enumerations: adVarChar value = 200; adInteger value = 3; adParamInput value = 1; adBoolean value = 11 '
full list http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp

```
 Dim adoCMD 
 Dim adoRS 
 Dim strSQL 
 Dim lRecordsAffected 

strSQL =  "insert into job account,reference,priority,colldate,deldate,onby,timestart,timeend,delname,deladd1,deladd2,deladd3,deltown,delcounty,delpostcode,goods,wgt,qty,plt,vol,haz,adr,adrpack,taillift,rigid,ringforbook,notes,phoneno,userid,confirmed,processed,adrname,adrchem,timestartc,timeendc,confno,jobno,fplt,hplt,qplt,coll1,coll2,coll3,coll4,coll5,collp,colname,printed,cheps,countryd,countryc,uniqueid,co2,carbon,am,pm,instructs,quote,validdel,validcol values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?  ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?  ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?  ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?  ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

Set adoCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With adoCMD
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandType = 1
.CommandText = strSQL
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("account", 200, 1, 16 , cCustcode)         '200 adVarChar'
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("reference", 200, 1, 40 , cReference)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("priority", 200, 1, 3 , cPriority)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("colldate", 200 ,1 , 8 , cCollDate)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deldate", 200, 1, 8 , cDelDate)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("onby", 3, 1, 4 , nOnby)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timestart", 200, 1, 4 , cTimestart)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timeend", 200, 1, 4 , cTimeend)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("delname", 200, 1, 40 , cDelname)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deladd1", 200, 1, 40 , cAdd1)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deladd2", 200, 1, 40 , cAdd2)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deladd3", 200, 1, 40 , cAdd3)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deltown", 200, 1, 40 , cAdd4)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("delcounty", 200, 1, 40 , cAdd5)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("delpostcode", 200, 1, 10 , cPostcode)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("goods", 200, 1, 40 , cGoods)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("wgt", 200, 1, 4 , nWgt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("qty", 200, 1, 4 , nQty)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("plt", 200, 1, 4 , nPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("vol", 200, 1, 4 , nVol)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("haz", 200, 1, 4 , nHaz)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adr", 200, 1, 10 , cadr)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adrpack", 200, 1, 10 , cAdrpack)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("taillift", 200, 1, 4 , nTl)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("rigid", 200, 1, 4 , nRi)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ringforbook", 200, 1, 4 , nBook)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("notes", 200, 1, 250 , cNotes)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("phoneno", 200, 1, 30 , cPhoneNo)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("userid", 200, 1, 4 , session("userid"))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("confirmed", 200, 1, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("processed", 200, 1, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adrname", 200, 1, 30 ,cAdrname)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adrchem", 200, 1, 10 ,cAdrchem)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timestartc", 200, 1, 4 ,ctimestartcol)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timeendc", 200, 1, 4 ,ctimeendcol)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("confno", 200, 1, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("jobno", 200, 1, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("fplt", 200, 1, 4 , nfPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("hplt", 200, 1, 4 , nhPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("qplt", 200, 1, 4 , nqPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll1", 200, 1, 30 ,cColl1)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll2", 200, 1, 30 ,cColl2)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll3", 200, 1, 30 ,cColl3)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll4", 200, 1, 30 ,cColl4)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll5", 200, 1, 30 ,cColl5)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("collp", 200, 1, 30 ,cCollp)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("colname", 200, 1, 30 ,cColname)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("printed", 11, 1, 1 ,false)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("cheps", 200, 1, 4 ,nCheps)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("countryd", 200, 1, 30 ,ccountryd)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("countryc", 200, 1, 30 ,ccountryc)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("uniqueid", 200, 1, 30 ,cUniqueId)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("co2", 200, 1, 10 , request.form("cC02"))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("carbon", 200, 1, 10 , request.form("cCarbon"))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("am", 200, 1, 4 ,nAM)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm", 200, 1, 4 ,nPM)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("instructs", 200, 1, 50 ,cSpecialInstruct)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("quote", 200, 1, 59 , trim(cQuoteId))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("validdel", 11, 1, 1 , lValidDel)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("validcol", 11, 1, 1 , lValidCol)
.Execute   ------> this line errors

end with
```

Comment: Start removing parameters until it works, then you know which one is broken.

Comment: The insert query syntax does not look right to me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977880(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Da Fuq with the query. it's mounstrous (i'm feel bad by the code reviewer :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets for the list of fields, hence the syntax error.

What you need to do:

```
strSQL =  "insert into job (account, ...,validcol) values (?, ..., ?)"
```